# За что отвечает опция "`services.SERVICE_NAME.build`" в docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker-compose

Анализирую учебный пример:

```
version: '3'

services:
  webpack:
    build: ./docker/webpack
    volumes:
      - ./src:/my_webpack/src
      - ./dist:/my_webpack/dist
      - ./docker/webpack/package.json:/my_webpack/package.json
      - ./docker/webpack/webpack.config.js:/my_webpack/webpack.config.js
    ports:
      - 2000:2000
```

Первое, что непонятно - какой смысл имеет `services.webpack.build`?

- Это ссылка на локальные файлы, контейнер или volume?
- Какой процесс выполняется благодаря этой настройке?
- Можно ли без неё обойтись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска контейнера в `docker-compose` нужно указать образ (image) с которого, контейнер будет создаваться. Например, это делают так:

```yml
services:
  db:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Это создаст контейнер на основе `redis:alpine` при `docker-compose up`.

Опция `build` используется тогда, когда у вас нет базового образа или вы его хотите собрать сами из `Dockerfile` ([подробнее](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)). В `build` указывается папка в которой будет находиться `Dockerfile` и потом при помощи `docker-compose build` вы можете собрать образ и `docker-compose up` запустить.

Это удобно когда у вас в `docker-compose` несколько сервисов и для них нужно собирать свои образы. Тогда чтобы не бегать по папкам и выполнять `docker build ...` вы можете настроить все раз и выполнять одну команда, которая соберет вам все.

> Это ссылка на локальные файлы, контейнер или volume?

Это путь с папке с `Dockerfile`. Можно провести аналогию:

```yml
services:
  webpack:
    build: ./docker/webpack
```

это

`docker build ./docker/webpack` (имя образа оно быберет само).

```yml
services:
  webpack:
    build: ./docker/webpack
    image: web:1.1
```

это

`docker build -t web:1.1 ./docker/webpack`

А "разширенный" вариант этой комманды:

```yml
services:
  webpack:
    image: web:1.1
    build:
      context: ./docker/webpack
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
```

это

`docker build -t web:1.1 -f Dockerfile-alternate ./docker/webpack`

> Можно ли без неё обойтись?

Да, можно собирать образы руками и просто указывать `image: <name>:<tag>`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! "Опция build используется тогда, когда у вас нет базового образа или вы его хотите собрать сами из Dockerfile" - странно, тот учебный пример, который я анализировал, имел базовый образ `FROM node:8.15.0` (оно и понятно, ведь Webpack-у нужен NodeJS). Но я так подозреваю, в нужно разделять два случая: чистый образ и базовый образ с каким-то содержимым, как в данном случае.